# Cambiar la animación de un botón al hacer click en él

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un botón a lo alto de mi página de la clase **`class="menu-bar"`**, es el típico botón de menú de tres líneas y lo he creado completamente desde html. A ese botón le di unas animaciones mediante CSS y ahora quiero que al hacerle click se ejecute la animación y cuando le vuelva hacer click de nuevo el botón vuelva a su estado de nuevo. A cada una de las líneas le di una animación en particular y al hacer  click mediante JS le agrego la clase que tiene las animaciones **`top` ,`middle`, `bottom`** a cada uno de los `div`.

Mi problema esta en que al hacer click las clases se añaden correctamente, pero, cuando vuelvo hacer click con la intención de quitar las clases que tienen las animaciones y dejar a mi botón en su estado inicial ya no funciona.

---

```js
const btnMenuTop = document.getElementById('btnMenuBar');
var lines = document.querySelectorAll(".line-menu");
var click = true;

if(click){

  btnMenuTop.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      lines.forEach((cadaLi,i)=>{
          if(i===0){
              lines[i].classList.add('top');
          }
          if(i===1){
              lines[i].classList.add("middle");
          }
          if(i===2){
              lines[i].classList.add("bottom");
          }
      })
  });
  click = false;
}else if(click == false){
  btnMenuTop.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      lines.forEach((cadaLi,i)=>{
          if(i===0){
              lines[i].classList.remove('top');
          }
          if(i===1){
              lines[i].classList.remove("middle");
          }
          if(i===2){
              lines[i].classList.remove("bottom");
          }
      })
      click = true;
  });
}
```

```css
 
/*CSS*/
.menu_bar{
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 3%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 999;
 }

 .line-menu{
    width: 40px;
    height: 2.4px;
    background-color: #fff;
 }

 .line1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
 }
 .line2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
 }
 .line3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
 }

 .top{
    left: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 2.4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation-name: lineTop;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }

 .middle{
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation-name: lineMiddle;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 1;
 }

  .bottom{
    top: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation-name: lineBottom;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }

 @keyframes lineTop {
    0%{
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        top: 50%;
    }
    100%{
        top: 70%;
       transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    }
 }
 @keyframes lineMiddle {
    0%{
        top: 50%;
    }
    100%{
       transform: rotateY(90deg);
       top: 70%;
    }
 }
 @keyframes lineBottom {
    0%{
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        top: 100%;
    }
    100%{
        top: 70%;
        transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    }
 }
```

```html
 <div class="menu_bar" id="btnMenuBar">
       <div class="line-menu line1 ">Line 1</div>
       <div class="line-menu line2 ">Line 2</div>
       <div class="line-menu line3 ">Line 3</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir los CSS que estás usando?

Comment: Ya lo añadi. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma se puede hacer lo que solicitas; simplemente implementé un **onClick** en tu HTML donde cada vez que pinchas se llama a dicha función implementada que es la que ejecuta tu código.

Además, puedes pulsar las veces que quieras que realizará la animación y al volver a pulsar de nuevo, volverá a su estado inicial.

```js
const btnMenuTop = document.getElementById('btnMenuBar');
var lines = document.querySelectorAll(".line-menu");
var click = true;

function animacion() {


    if(click){

      btnMenuTop.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
          lines.forEach((cadaLi,i)=>{
              if(i===0){
                  lines[i].classList.add('top');
              }
              if(i===1){
                  lines[i].classList.add("middle");
              }
              if(i===2){
                  lines[i].classList.add("bottom");
              }
          })
      });
      click = false;
    }else if(click == false){
      btnMenuTop.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
          lines.forEach((cadaLi,i)=>{
              if(i===0){
                  lines[i].classList.remove('top');
              }
              if(i===1){
                  lines[i].classList.remove("middle");
              }
              if(i===2){
                  lines[i].classList.remove("bottom");
              }
          })

      });
      click = true;
    }
    
}
```

```css
/*CSS*/
.menu_bar{
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 3%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 999;
 }

 .line-menu{
    width: 40px;
    height: 2.4px;
    background-color: #fff;
 }

 .line1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
 }
 .line2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
 }
 .line3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
 }

 .top{
    left: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 2.4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation-name: lineTop;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }

 .middle{
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation-name: lineMiddle;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 1;
 }

  .bottom{
    top: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation-name: lineBottom;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }

 @keyframes lineTop {
    0%{
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        top: 50%;
    }
    100%{
        top: 70%;
       transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    }
 }
 @keyframes lineMiddle {
    0%{
        top: 50%;
    }
    100%{
       transform: rotateY(90deg);
       top: 70%;
    }
 }
 @keyframes lineBottom {
    0%{
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        top: 100%;
    }
    100%{
        top: 70%;
        transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="menu_bar" id="btnMenuBar" onClick="animacion()">
       <div class="line-menu line1 ">Line 1</div>
       <div class="line-menu line2 ">Line 2</div>
       <div class="line-menu line3 ">Line 3</div>
 </div>
```